# Download Bitcoin, Etherium, Ripple rates 1min candles

Tags: buy-bitcoins, exchange-rate, ethereum

is there any possibility to download archive with rates for Bitcoin, Etherium, Ripple VS USD?
I need 1m ... 1w candles.
I would like to find such service and download it on daily basis.

Comment: You can get those data with API, unfortunately I don't know anywhere where you can download archived data.

Comment: Yeah, I saw some services with API, can you recommend some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of exchanges have a limit on how many candles that can be returned per request.
If you can't be arsed to do several requests.

You can use:
https://cryptowat.ch/docs/api#ohlc

**Example usage 1:**

Fetch from GDAX - BTC/USD, 1-min OHLC candlestick after the date and time 19.12.17 00:00:00

```
https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/gdax/btcusd/ohlc?periods=60&after=1513641600
```

**Example usage 2:**

Fetch from Bitfinex - XRP/USD, 1-week OHLC candlestick after the date and time 01.12.17 00:00:00

```
https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/bitfinex/xrpusd/ohlc?periods=604800&after=1512000000
```

You can use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert the Unix Time stamp to human readable format.

Also btw, I found some archives here: https://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/ that might be of interest.

Comment: `after` and `before` parameters don't work in cryptowat.ch's api.You get the latest 6000 candles and that's it as far as I can tell (November 2018)